# Initiating a method only once

Tags: android, methods, android-studio, alarmmanager, android-alarms

So this is probably a very basic question, but I couldn't find an answer for it that has worked for me. I have a method "notificationsetter()" which starts an alarm for displaying a notification and goes off every 24hrs. The problem is, I have to call the method only once, because if I use it at a time AFTER the alarm has gone off, the notification appears immediately (for example, alarm is set to 7AM, I use the method 10AM, the notification appears immediately at 10AM).

So I created this code in my MainActivity which is in onCreate():

```
boolean notificationtrue = false;
    if(notificationtrue==false) {
        notificationsetter();
        notificationtrue = false;

    }
```

So the code "should" call the method once, and then, as notificationtrue is always set to true, it is never called again. The problem here is, notificationtrue is displayed gray and android studio says:

"The value false assigned to notificationtrue is never used"

That means, my code won't work. Is there another way to call the method only once?

Comment: Is there a reason that you're setting the value to false and then immediately checking if it's false?

Comment: good point. well, my intention was to set the method false the first time, so when the if statement happened once, it is set to true and never happens again.

Answer (score 0):

Save a boolean in your preference like this

```
/**
     * Checks that application runs first time and write flag at SharedPreferences
     *
     * @return true if 1st time
     */
    private boolean isFirstTime() {

        SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean ranBefore = preferences.getBoolean(RetailStoreConstants.FIRST_TIME, false);
        if (!ranBefore) {
            // first time
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean(RetailStoreConstants.FIRST_TIME, true);
            editor.commit();
        }
        return !ranBefore;
    }
```

then do what you are doing with this boolean.

Comment: what are/is retailstoreconstants and why can't android studio resolve them/it?

Comment: It's just some constant use any string "demo" for eg in place of it.

Up vote and accept the answer it this work.

Comment: If i put a string there, android studio can't resolve FIRST_TIME

Comment: dude you have to give string type  like eg "FIRST_TYPE". This is the name of preference.

Comment: sorry I am a total beginner in programming and only know some basic stuff.

Comment: it's ok no problem here to help you. Also please accept this answer it it worked,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74405/discussion-between-ankit-and-just-deko).